# gzipped jQuery ajax fails in firefox with "401 UNAUTHORIZED"

Tags: ajax, jquery, gzip, mod-wsgi

Not sure how to debug this - I am sending some gzipped json data back from my django server.

(Through a backbone fetch() call... which in turn calles jQuery.ajax).  On the django server, I set:

- response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
- response['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'

And I didn't set any additional options to the ajax call (aside from Backbone.js defaults).  This works fine in Chrome, but in firefox, I see the request just spinning forever in firebug, with a status of **401 UNAUTHORIZED**.

It's funny, because it works in firefox on my local test server from django directly, but not when it's running through an SSL connection via Apache and mod_wsgi.

Do I need to do something special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to debug is to read the error message.

A mistake in the testing environment was keeping the login from authorizing correctly in firefox, so the page wasn't authorized, and returning a 401 error.